# Why can I only clone using my username in the url of the repository?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

Last days I've been only able to clone repositories by using my user name in it.

Suppose the url is  https://github.com/company/repo.git. When I try

```
$ git clone https://github.com/company/repo.git
```

it says that the repository was not found. It used to work fine before. Now I have to do

```
$ git clone https://username@github.com/company/repo.git
```

in order for it to work. I think I messed up some configuration when I used `$ gh auth login` and now I can't seem to let things working as they were before and it's causing me a lot of trouble.

How can I make things work as they did before?

Comment: What's the output of `git config credential.helper`?

Comment: To augment @ElpieKay's question a bit, readers will need to know the result of `git config --get-all credential.helper` to answer your question. A `git clone` or `git fetch` here may use more than one helper; the `git config` line will show only the *last* line, if there are several such lines.

Comment: When I write any of these commands, the output is `manager-core`.